# controlling the properties of a sprite's child sprites

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I have a sprite in which I have added other sprites.
Something like:

```
var sp_main:Sprite = new Sprite();
var sp_group:Sprite = new Sprite();

for(i:int = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   var temp:Sprite = new Sprite();

   sp_group.addChild(temp);
}

sp_main.addChild(sp_group);

//this part doesn't seem to work... i don't mind doing it another way, but 
//am unaware of one.
sp_main["sp_group"].alpha = 0.0;
```

Any thoughts on how I might accomplish this or something similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sp_main.getChildAt(0).alpha = 0;
```

*(assumes sp_main contains only sp_group).*

**or**

```
sp_main.getChildAt(sp_main.getChildIndex(sp_group)).alpha = 0;
```

**or (if you've named sp_group)**

```
sp_group.name = "sp_group";
sp_main.getChildByName("sp_group").alpha = 0;
```